# I am facing Laravel collective/html class form not found error

Tags: forms, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I did all the step at cmd clear cache,route,update,optimize artisan but nothing worked.any there suggestion for it?
this is .json file

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "laravelcollective/html" : "^5.2"
},
```

this is my view...config/app is also ok

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
        <!-- <div class="container"> -->
            <h1>Create Post</h1>
            <!-- <div class="content"> -->
                {!! Form::open() !!}
                    <input type="text" name="content">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit">
                </form>

            <!-- </div>
        </div> -->
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you done all steps from this site ?

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#installation

Try: `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 0):

If you've manually included `laravelcollective/html` in the composer.json file, you first need to update the vendor folder. You can do this using:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Then, run the following to update the autoloader:

```
php artisan optimize
```